# How to read 4 Millions lines from SQLite and write them to a file fast?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my current android project I am developing an application, that records communication data. Each data packet is stored in a single row inside my SQLite database. One of my test recordings has 3.888.530 lines.

The application shall support an export functionality, to write this data into a text file in a JSON format. Currently I am using the **LIMIT** function, read packages of 5.000 lines and write them to the file. This is really slow. I think reading 15.000 lines from the database and writing them to the file needs more than 60s.

For writing I am using a PrintStream. A string is created and the conversion to a byte array is given to the stream.

I read my data packets with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_packet 
INNER JOIN data_packet_type 
    ON data_packet.data_packet_type_id = data_packet_type.id 
WHERE recording_id = 7 
ORDER BY time_received ASC 
LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 0
```

The query is executed with calling:

```
db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Afterwards I run through the data with a cursor and store the data.

I hope there is a way to export the data much faster.
Thanks.

Comment: just read 'em all, not in chunks

Comment: 60 seconds? That's insanely slow, you must be doing something wrong. Fetching 15k records from a database should take a few hundred milliseconds at most. Probably less that 100.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your problem lies. You seem to be assuming it is coming from the query; my guess is that it is coming from your disk-writing I/O for the JSON.

Comment: What do you mean by trace view?

Comment: You should **index** your fields

Comment: PrintStream is bad as it does not buffer the written output. A BufferedWriter with a large buffer (~16k) would be better.

Comment: also like @CommonsWare suggested for testing purposes drop the writing to the file and see what happens - that way you will find the bottleneck

Comment: "What do you mean by trace view?" -- by Traceview, I mean [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). See also http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/traceview/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you really should drop the LIMIT function.

By using LIMIT / OFFSET you force the database to read over the same chunks of rows over and over again, specially when you use ORDER BY and/or JOINS.

The other question, I would think about (when I would have the db scheme) is if you really need the JOIN. For me, it looks as it could be avoided, but of course the database could optimize the JOIN away, what I can not say either without having a scheme and maybe an EXPLAIN.

When this does not help, I would recommend to do the reading without the writing, so you can see, if your are database or Write-Bound in this case (as Robert hinted, that PrintStream could be bad for the writing -- when much data is written, it well could be the writing that is slow).

But without db scheme and the information, if the read or the write is the problem, a better answer is really difficult!

Comment: How to measure the time that is needed for the query?

Comment: Just remove the writing part (do only the query) and measure as you did before.

Comment: With running through the cursor?

Comment: Yes, with running threw the cursor, to have the same condition for the reading.

Comment: Ok I measured the time it takes to run through the cursor only. 1.750.000 lines took around 4 minutes on my nexus 10. I removed the JOIN ,the ORDER BY and the LIMIT part. Is this is realistic value?

Comment: I simply don't know, since I don't have a Nexus. But it sounds much better than 60s for 15k. Now of course you made the technical error, that you changed at two details simultaneously. So the result is not conclusive. But I would precede by adding the write again and use the BufferedWriter as Robert hinted. When the speed is still to bad for you, than you might consider adding indexes or changing the table structure. It also could be, that the amount of data (how much is contained in one line??) is simply to much for so a little device to handle in short time.